# How do I execute a block of code with PostSharp when the application exits?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

Presently, I am checking the method name in the OnMethodBoundaryAspect.OnExit method:

```
[Serializable]
public class TimerAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if(eventArgs.Method.DeclaringType.Name == "Program" && eventArgs.Method.Name == "Main")
            //do things
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is ugly and feels kludgy. Is there a more robust way to detect application exit with PostSharp?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use PostSharp to do that.

You can detect whether the application domain is exiting by using some features of System.AppDomain:

- AppDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload()
- AppDomain.ProcessExit
- AppDomain.DomainUnload